# finding and extracting a string from an array of strings

Tags: java, xml, string, find

I have a an xml document that I have saved in String. And the String is something like this:

```
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" standalone=\"no\"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing\"><axis2:ServiceGroupId xmlns:axis2=\"http://ws.apache.org/namespaces/axis2\" wsa:IsReferenceParameter=\"true\">urn:uuid:2BC5F552AF3179755C1348038695049</axis2:ServiceGroupId><wsa:To>http://localhost:8081/axis2/services/TCAQSRBase</wsa:To><wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:599362E68F35A38AFA1348038695733</wsa:MessageID><wsa:Action>http://www.transcat-plm.com/TCAQSRBase/TCAQSR_BAS_ServerGetOsVariable</wsa:Action></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><ns1:TCAQSR_BAS_ServerGetOsVariableInput xmlns:ns1=\"http://www.transcat-plm.com/TCAQSRBase/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:type=\"ns1:TCAQSR_BAS_ServerGetOsVariableInputType\"><ns1:TCAQSR_BAS_BaseServerGetInputKey>USERNAME</ns1:TCAQSR_BAS_BaseServerGetInputKey></ns1:TCAQSR_BAS_ServerGetOsVariableInput></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I dont know how it would represent in the string.

But I would want to extract the term between `<axis2:ServiceGroupId xmlns:axis2="http://ws.apache.org/namespaces/axis2">` and `</axis2:ServiceGroupId>`
Which is a urn:uuid: and would like to save the result in a String. I know of xpath, but in my case, i cannot use xpath.

And would really appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: @sp00m I am sorry mate, i have no prior knowledge about this thing. And I don't exactly know what an xml parser is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int startPos = xmlString.indexOf("<axis2...>") + "<axis2...>".length();
int endPos = xmlString.indexOf("</value2...>");
String term = xmlString.substring(startPos,endPos);
```

I hope I get your question right.
You can do it in one line too.

Comment: I have problems inserting `<axis2:ServiceGroupId xmlns:axis2="http://ws.apache.org/namespaces/axis2">` because it already has "" in the expression and again I have to add "" in the indexOf term, and I am getting an error.

Comment: You have to escape your " inside the String change it to \"

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. That way really fast and helpful.

Comment: @Kishorepandey the answer above is quite bruteforce, you can have only one urn:uuid: data at any time. with my solution, you can collect multiple values in a list, too. please be fair.

Comment: if you have more then one urn:uuid in your xml you have to cut the xml after you find the first one and put it in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions. Parsing your whole XML String with a weird regex like
**`<axis2:ServiceGroupId xmlns:axis2="http://ws.apache.org/namespaces/axis2">(.+?)  </axis2:ServiceGroupId>`** could solve your particular problem.

A useful snippet that I've written for your particular problem:

```
    String yourInput = "<wsa:ReferenceParameters><axis2:ServiceGroupId xmlns:axis2=\"http://ws.apache.org/namespaces/axis2\">urn:uuid:2BC5F552AF3179755C1348038695049</axis2:ServiceGroupId></wsa:ReferenceParameters>";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern
            .compile("<axis2:ServiceGroupId xmlns:axis2=\"http://ws.apache.org/namespaces/axis2\">(.+?)</axis2:ServiceGroupId>");
    Matcher matcher = pattern
            .matcher(yourInput);
    matcher.find();
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
```

**matcher.group(1)** returns the String desired, you can assign it to another variable and use that variable etc.

Comment: How can i do that? I have no previous knowledge about this. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: @Kishorepandey I've included a code snippet in my post, I hope it helps. if it does so, please upvote and accept :) thanks.

Comment: where would be my input string?

Comment: @Kishorepandey I have edited my answer. Take a look at it now. mathcer() method of Pattern class will take your long input String which is derived from XML content.

Comment: Thanks for replying mate. But when I use your code, I get an error illegal state exception- No match found. I have updated my string above in the question. Its not like regular xml.